# How do I update CodeMirror v5 code to v6?

Tags: node.js, codemirror

I'm using a [Gatsby application](https://github.com/ines/course-starter-python) which uses [CodeMirror version 5](https://codemirror.net/5/doc/manual.html#usage). I'm trying to update this application to the most recent version of Gatsby/Node.js and this requires the CodeMirror v5 code below to be ported to [v6](https://codemirror.net/docs/ref/). The update from v5 to v6 is daunting - as they broke up the package into several bits. Can someone help me understand how the v5 code below should now be called in v6? The documentation is just so overwhelming that I can't make sense of what went where

version 5 CodeMirror code in `src/components/juniper.js`:

```
import CodeMirror from `codemirror`

const cm = new CodeMirror(this.inputRef, {
            value: this.props.children.trim(),
            mode: this.props.lang,
            theme: this.props.theme,
        })
```

and then a python load in `gatsby-browser.js`:

```
import python from 'codemirror/mode/python/python'
```

Comment: Does this help? https://codemirror.net/docs/migration/